# getting uninitialized error with instantiation of HTML::TokeParser

Tags: perl

I am getting undefined errors while using HTML::TokeParser.

```
print $agent->content();
my $stream = HTML::TokeParser->new($agent->{content});
```

line 1 - I do get desired output from my print statement.

line 2 - Error: Use of uninitialized value $stream in print.

No clue why it could not be working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scalar argument to the `HTML::TokeParser` constructor is treated as a filename or filehandle, and failure to open the file will cause the constructor to return `undef` and set `$!`.

If you want to pass the actual HTML to the constructor, you have to use a scalar reference:

```
my $stream = HTML::TokeParser->new( \$agent->content )
```

Comment: As @choroba says, `$agent->content` is not the same thing as `$agent->{content}`. The former calls a method called `<Package>::content` (depending on the package that `$agent` has been blessed into, and the latter treats `$agent` as a hash reference and looks for the value associated with the string`"content"`. For some types of object they will both return the same thing, but there is nothing in Perl that requires this to be the case.

Comment: Because you said it worked: "ine 1 - I do get desired output from my print statement."

Answer (score 1):

`$agent->content` is not the same as `$agent->{content}`. The former is a method call, the second is a hash dereference.